# Endomorphism of Central Simple Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $A\in\mathscr{C}(F)$, i.e. $A$ is a central simple algebra.

> Show that $\text{End}_F(A)\cong M_n(F)$ as $F$-algebras where $n=\dim A$.

My idea is to consider $A$ as a $F$-vector space, then $\text{End}_F(A)$ is a linear transformation from $A$ to $A$, thus upon picking a basis of $A$, it is isomorphic to $M_n(F)$.

Is the idea correct? Thanks.

Comment: Look up the Artin-Wedderburn theorem, this is an easy corollary to that theorem.

Comment: If $End_F(A)$ is supposed to be the $F$-module endomorphisms, then you don't need any theorem, yes, picking a basis gives the result.